# What is the sequence of cleaning up the resources in a namespace of Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I issue a command

```
kubectl delete namespace <mynamespace>
```

What is the sequence followed by kubernetes to clean up the resources inside a namespace? Does it start with services followed by containers? Is it possible to control the order?

Stack:
I am using `HELM` to define kubernetes resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible and it will start in parallel.

`kube-controller-manager` has few flags to control the speed/sync of different resources.

You can check `--concurrent-*` flags for controller manager on link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/

Comment: The problem is with the kubernetes services, when I issue the `kubectl delete` what I observed, it cleans the k8s services first, and the pods are not able to communicate with in a namespace.

Comment: Yes, it cleans in parallel but as services are light weight object in k8s, cleaned faster than pods. You can even observe, deployments are removed faster than the pods owned by them. If you face any issue because of this, handle those situation some other way.